# Create new shapely polygon by subtracting the intersection with another polygon

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I have two shapely MultiPolygon instances (made of lon,lat points) that intersect at various parts. I'm trying to loop through, determine if there's an intersection between two polygons, and then create a new polygon that excludes that intersection. From the attached image, I basically don't want the red circle to overlap with the yellow contour, I want the edge to be exactly where the yellow contour starts.

I've tried following the instructions [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11987/polygon-overlay-with-shapely) but it doesn't change my output at all, plus I don't want to merge them into one cascading union. I'm not getting any error messages, but when I add these MultiPolygons to a KML file (just raw text manipulation in python, no fancy program) they're still showing up as circles without any modifications.

```
# multipol1 and multipol2 are my shapely MultiPolygons
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from itertools import combinations
from shapely.geometry import Polygon,MultiPolygon

outmulti = []
for pol in multipoly1:
    for pol2 in multipoly2:
        if pol.intersects(pol2)==True:
            # If they intersect, create a new polygon that is
            # essentially pol minus the intersection
            intersection = pol.intersection(pol2)
            nonoverlap = pol.difference(intersection)
            outmulti.append(nonoverlap)

        else:
            # Otherwise, just keep the initial polygon as it is.
            outmulti.append(pol)

finalpol = MultiPolygon(outmulti)
```

[image: Polygon Overlap]

Comment: I vote to close this question as "Not reproducible" because the code in the question is *correct* and OP [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459496/create-new-shapely-polygon-by-subtracting-the-intersection-with-another-polygon#comment66242715_39459906) that the bug was elsewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you can use the [`symmetric_difference`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.symmetric_difference) between theses two polygons, combined by the difference with the second polygon to achieve what you want to do (the *symmetric difference* will brings you the non-overlapping parts from the two polygons, on which are removed parts of the polygon 2 by the *difference*). I haven't tested but it might look like :

```
# multipol1 and multipol2 are my shapely MultiPolygons
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from itertools import combinations
from shapely.geometry import Polygon,MultiPolygon

outmulti = []
for pol in multipoly1:
    for pol2 in multipoly2:
        if pol.intersects(pol2)==True:
            # If they intersect, create a new polygon that is
            # essentially pol minus the intersection
            nonoverlap = (pol.symmetric_difference(pol2)).difference(pol2)
            outmulti.append(nonoverlap)

        else:
            # Otherwise, just keep the initial polygon as it is.
            outmulti.append(pol)

finalpol = MultiPolygon(outmulti)
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped! I realized the error was partly because of how I had set up a different loop later in my code... Oops.

Comment: Any idea how to keep the overlapping part as a polygon

Comment: @Faisal according to my understanding (and without more information) I guess you just want the intersection (so with the code of this question something like `pol.intersection(pol2)`